# Query not collecting all of data

Tags: sql, time

I have a screen created to display a data from a query. The query is supposed collect the daily production of materials from a process. The query is below:

```
Select SUM(ltv.val) "CE" FROM LADLE_TAP_VALUE ltv, LADLE_TAP_ID lti where ltv.id=108 AND ltv.ladletapid =lti.ladletapid and lti.tapid IN (Select ti.TapID FROM tap_index ti WHERE ti.tapno like 'CE%' AND ti.starttime>=to_date('20120426', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') and ti.endtime<=to_date('20120427 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

The problem that I am facing is that occasionally that the starttime is near end of one day and the endtime is during the first hours of the next day.
I am not sure how to make that adjustment with the time handling portion of my query. This is an issue because every day I missing production from my display that should be there.

```
tap_index table
tapid tapno plant taphole drytap status startime endtime slagstart readytime 
21437   CN121348    1   1   1   0   26-APR-12 06:00:26  26-APR-12 07:42:41  26-APR-12 06:56:34  26-APR-12 06:00:00
21436   CE121347    1   2   1   0   26-APR-12 03:21:10  26-APR-12 05:40:48  26-APR-12 04:39:27  26-APR-12 03:21:00
21435   CN121346    1   1   1   0   26-APR-12 01:48:07  26-APR-12 03:01:23  26-APR-12 02:27:34  26-APR-12 01:48:00
21434   CE121345    1   2   1   0   25-APR-12 23:27:23  26-APR-12 01:28:08  26-APR-12 00:44:09  25-APR-12 23:27:00
21433   CN121344    1   1   1   0   25-APR-12 21:18:24  25-APR-12 23:07:17  25-APR-12 22:31:04  25-APR-12 21:18:00
21432   CE121343    1   2   1   0   25-APR-12 19:55:08  25-APR-12 20:58:59  25-APR-12 20:22:39  25-APR-12 19:55:00
21431   CN121342    1   1   1   0   25-APR-12 18:09:28  25-21422    CE121333    1   2   1   0   24-APR-12 22:56:17  25-APR-12 00:29:23  24-APR-12 23:32:27  24-APR-12 22:56:00
```

21421   CN121332    1   1   1   0   24-APR-12 20:49:25  24-APR-12 22:36:37  24-APR-12 21:59:30  24-APR-12 20:49:00
21420   CE121331    1   2   1   0   24-APR-12 18:15:12  24-APR-12 20:30:16  24-APR-12 19:19:42  24-APR-12 18:15:00
21419   CN121330    1   1   1   0   24-APR-12 16:06:06  24-APR-12 17:55:12  24-APR-12 17:02:33  24-APR-12 16:06:00
21418   CE121329    1   2   1   0   24-APR-12 14:04:36  24-APR-12 15:44:40  24-APR-12 14:50:33  24-APR-12 14:04:00

Comment: Please provide your schema, sample data, and desired output.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are attempting to pull all of the records for a given date. Generally the best approach is to construct a query with this logic:

- DateField < trunc(:EndDate) + 1: get all records before the day after your EndDate
- DateField >= trunc(:StartDate): get all records on or after the beginning of your StartDate

I mention "trunc" since often parameterized inputs to queries like this include a time portion. trunc removes the time portion from the date.

In your example, I would imagine the query could read as follows - I simply changed the "ti.endtime" to use "<" instead of "<=" so that you wouldn't get records from the start of April 27th.

```
Select SUM(ltv.val) "CE" 
  FROM LADLE_TAP_VALUE ltv, LADLE_TAP_ID lti 
 where ltv.id=108 
   AND ltv.ladletapid =lti.ladletapid 
   and lti.tapid IN (Select ti.TapID 
                       FROM tap_index ti 
                      WHERE ti.tapno like 'CE%' AND ti.starttime>=to_date('20120426', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') and ti.endtime < to_date('20120427 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: I may have been unintentionally misleading. I want capture all of the data that for day X grabbing the data if its starts time is before this start of the start of previous day and the end time is during the current day. Meaning fetch the data if ti.starttime is 04132012 23:10:13 and ti.endtime is 04142012 01:32:21, if my query wants all data for the 04142012.

Answer (score 0):

`ti.starttime >= $start and ti.endtime <= $end` selects all spans fitting completely inside [$start..$end].

`ti.endtime >= $start and ti.starttime <= $end` will select all spans intersecting [$start..$end] somehow.